# Comparing Char arrays

Tags: c++

So in my `TrieNode` class, I have a `char* word[]`. I have a method in which one of the parameters is a `char* missSpelledWord`. I am checking if the word is off by one letter. I have a for loop and then I have this if statement:

```
   if(missSpelledWord[i] != node->word[i]){
   //code
}
```

I keep getting an error saying `comparison between pointer and integer ('int' and 'char *')`
The `char*` word array is in my `TrieNode` class and I can only access it by doing `node->word[i]`.
How can I compare this data member and compare it to a normal `char*` array?

This my `TrieNode` class

```
class TrieNode{
public: 
    bool isWord;
    char word[100][20];
    TrieNode* letter[alphabetSize];
};
```

Comment: share you node structure definition

Comment: `node-> word[i]` is a `char *`, probably `missSpelledWord[i]` is a char

Comment: Yeah, I want to compare them but like you mentioned that is not possible so is there another way in which I can compare these two?

Answer (score 0):

As you mentioned, you have array of char pointers `char* word[]` and you have char pointer `char* missSpelledWord`. This means that your statement `missSpelledWord[i] != node->word[i]` means "compare ith character from missSpelledWord with ith array of characters in node->word".

In fact you want something like:

```
missSpelledWord[i] != node->word[n][i]
```

Here "n" is nth word and "i" is character position.

Compiler assumes that array pointer is an int, so it complains about comparison between char and int. Array is just pointer and "i" is offset applied to this pointer. 
`word[n]` is equivalent to `*(word+(sizeof(char)*n))`.

Comment: Then that would mean I would have a second for loop that is the size of the char* word array?

Comment: Thank you. I understand. I will give it a try.

Comment: It depends what do you want to achieve. You have 2D array here ```word[100][20];```, so you have 20 words, 100 characters each. Do you want to check all of those words or you intended to have only one char array?

Comment: So I am inserting words into my trie so all the words should go into the char* array word in my TrieNodeClass. I just set the size to 100 and character length to 20 for the time being, but I want to compare the missSpelledWord with the same length in the word array.

Comment: Then you need two loops. One over node->word and nested one over node->word[n]. If you use C++11, then you can use range-based loop.
```for (const auto& word : node->word)```